# Does a trumpet play at a tritone lower without lip vibration?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, pressure, acoustics

My trumpet teacher noticed that if you blow into a trumpet for warm-up, *without any lip vibration*, there is still a slightly audible pitch which is a tritone lower than "expected" in the following sense:

For example, if none of the vents are pressed on a Bb trumpet (e.g. G with lip vibration), and air is blown through it, there is a slightly audible C# pitch. If you depress the middle vent, instead of Gb, a C pitch is audible, and so on.

The effect is consistent on several Bb trumpets he tested. Is there a mechanical explanation?

Comment: Can you grab some Bb cornets and compare performance?  Just out of interest; I think Victor nailed it pretty well.   Oh,  BTW  do you think the tritone-ish pitch is above or below the fundamental G?

Answer (score 2):

There are three points to be noticed:

- If you just blow without closing the lips, you would change the boundary condition.
- The trumpet waveguide is not "nicely predictible", the approximation of an open tube does not work cause the bore variations $S(x)$. You need to solve this kind of beasts for reasonable 1D propagating pressure approximation:

$$
\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial (\ln S(x))}{\partial x}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{c_0^2}\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial t^2}
$$

and the change in boundary conditions can move the mode peaks in various manner.

- Most importantly: **The driving mechanism is in this case the vortex sound. Therefore the instrument resonates not on its impedance maxima but minima (generall difference between flute-like and trumpet-like instruments). That might do the impression of sounding in between the usual trumpet natural tones.**